# Why i cannot render my KML service in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have been trying to render my KML service in the google maps by the following.

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
   url: 'http://DomainName/GeoSystem/redrawKML'
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

But I am getting `undefined` as a result with *ctaLayer object* when i have checked the status.

But the same service is working good, If i have tried to parse the KML service with geoXML parser. Now, I am confused and having no idea . Why I can not render my KML Service with the google maps KML Layer in google maps.

Any help is much appreciated.

My Woring code with GeoXML library follows.

```
var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map : map,
    singleInfoWindow : true
});
geoXml.parse('http://DomainName/GeoSystem/redrawKML');
```

The following is My KML Content which will be produced by my rest service ( `http://DomainName/GeoSystem/redrawKML`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
<Document>
    <name>My KML Document</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Fort Worth</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <description>Fort Worth , Dallas</description>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="GeoRegionId">
                <value>1</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name="PolygonId">
                <value>132</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>-97.47551,32.778615 -97.45079,32.79651 -97.437744,32.798242 -97.420578,32.806322 -97.417145,32.813824 -97.34848,32.843251 -97.338867,32.842674 -97.317581,32.838635 -97.292862,32.838058 -97.264709,32.839212 -97.229691,32.840943 -97.207718,32.831135 -97.206345,32.814978 -97.211838,32.802859 -97.212524,32.758985 -97.224884,32.739927 -97.225571,32.716822 -97.240677,32.691977 -97.239304,32.667125 -97.245483,32.661922 -97.281876,32.6625 -97.304535,32.668859 -97.334061,32.663656 -97.380066,32.671749 -97.402725,32.684464 -97.459717,32.683308 -97.47139,32.695444 -97.478943,32.720288 -97.482376,32.741082 -97.47551,32.778615
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer.

If KMLLayer of google maps API3 has to display contents, The `KML File should be in PUBLICALLY ACCESIBLE`. Then only the google server can parse the file and will render it in the google maps.

Since I am developing in my local environment. `Google Server can not parse the KML File which i am providing. That is why the contents are not rendered in the Google maps.`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [KML limits of Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport) ? If you surpass the limit on feature quantity or file weight, then nothing will be displayed.

**Edit**:
I uploaded your kml to my public dropbox folder. And I'm loading it fine with

```
var fortw = new google.maps.KmlLayer({    
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3133731/fortworth.kml',  
    map: map  
});
```

Comment: I am just rendering single polygon from my service. I am pretty sure that, It is not crossing the limitations.

Comment: In that case, please provide the real URL to try to load it myself.

Comment: Really sorry to say, I dont have online server to share my KML files. Better I will update my question with my Service output. Actually I am producing the Kml content by restful service.

Comment: Man, if you're going to vote negative for every answer that doesn't solve the issue, you're going to have trouble getting answered to.